# PHP cron job not running log via file_put_contents()

Tags: php, cron

I am running a cron job every minute which runs a loop; I am outputting the results from each loop into a log file. This function is inside a class, and runs absolutely fine when the function is called manually. However, when the function is called via a cron job, file_put_contents() does nothing (the rest of this function works fine i.e. the table insertion).

```
protected function updatePair( $time, $pair_reference, $price, $exchange_id ) {

    $exchange_reference = get_field('reference', $exchange_id);

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . $pair_reference . '_' . $exchange_reference;

    // Insert time and price into table
    $wpdb->insert($table, array(
        "time"  => $time,
        "price" => $price
    ));

    //Write action to txt log
    $log  = "Pair: ".$pair_reference.' - '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL.
            "Attempt: Finished".PHP_EOL.
            "-------------------------".PHP_EOL;
    //-
    file_put_contents('log/exchange.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);

}
```

Comment: did you have write persmission to log folder . check your permission if it's not change the permission like this chmod 0777 -R log/

Comment: The function writes to the log file when called manually, i.e. $class->updatePair( ... ) but just not when the cron decides to do it. Are different permissions needed for the cron? Excuse the novice question.

Comment: you need to give permission to apache user

Comment: No such luck, permissions etc all set as specified.

Comment: can you show your crontab call too

Comment: It's actually running on WP cron as a hook, not via crontab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone face the same problem in the future, the problem was with the permissions, to solve the problem you need to change the permission of the php script file, it must have the write permission), to do that:

1. **Using FTP Client (i.e. Filezilla)**:
   right click on the script file, and choose File permission, give write permission to the user and group of users (i.e. 766)
2. **Using Terminal**:

   chmod 766 /path/to/php_script

Answer (score 2):

First make sure log folder is exist or you can check by below code:

```
if(!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/log') && !is_dir(__DIR__ . '/log')){
    mkdir(__DIR__ . '/log');
}
```

Second use absolute path:

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/log/exchange.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Function still not running on cron, but fine on a manual call. Very strange indeed.

Comment: How add your cronjob? Are you use `crontab -u user -e`?

Comment: WP cron for WordPress, haven't used crontab in this particular instance.

Comment: It's wordpress cron issue and not related only to cron. Please tag your question with **wordpress** to helping you a wordpress man. 
See this, maybe useful: [Can't access wp_filesystem in cron function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195209/cant-access-wp-filesystem-in-cron-function)